# Am I doing the proper steps for this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I don't need the answer, I just need to know if I am plugging in the numbers right.

Suppose $f(x)= e^{2x}.$ We know that if $h$ is small, then $f'(x) \simeq \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}.$ Find the approximative value of $f'(1)$ with $h=0.01$.

So, I am plugging in the data like this:

$$(e(1 + 0.01)^2-e^{2(1)})/0.01.$$

Then, I find the answer by finding the derivative of the formula above, right?

Comment: The equation $$f'(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ is false.

Comment: Yeah, i know its supposed to be f(x) but, in this case, it's the derivative

Comment: No. It's neither $f(x)$ nor $f'(x).$

Comment: so is it just 1?

Comment: @EleanorMcArthur, welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, welcome to *MSE!* For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). It will come in handy later, I promise you!

Secondly, you should plug in the following: $$f'(1) \simeq \frac{f(1.01) - f(1)}{0.01} = \frac{e^{2.02} - e^2}{0.01} \simeq 14.92688.$$ This is not yet very close to the actual value of $f'(1) = 2 e^2 \simeq 14.7781,$ but making $h$ smaller and smaller will get you there- this is basically the definition of the derivative.

Comment: Thanks!  I get it now!  I just needed an example.  I think I can do the rest of this now.

Comment: You're most welcome! :)

Comment: I was confused bc I know f(x)=e^(2x) with f ' (1) is around 2e^2 and couldn't get close to it through the formula.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=e^{2x}$, then by definition
$$
f'(1) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{2(1+h)}-e^2}{h}
$$
If you want to approximate $f'(1)$, then it is valid to plug in $h=0.01$, so that
$$
f'(1) \approx \frac{e^{2(1+0.01)}-e^2}{0.01}
$$
The accuracy of this approximation depends on the value of $h$ (which is not a dummy variable as it is in the limiting expression).